# Is it a good idea to use One-time-passwords for securing REST-Applications?

Tags: rest, security, http, ssl, https

In the last weeks I started building REST-Producing/Consuming web applications and therefore started to worry about the security of my communication.

I made up the following procedure:

1. One REST-Consumer and one REST-Producer secretly negotiate a common secret and initialize a One-Time-Password(OTP)-Component with this secret.
2. With every Request and Response the Clients send an OTP.

   - This OTP is generated by the OTP-Component based on the negotiated secret.
   - The other partner generates the same order of OTPs and checks whether the sent OTP is correct and accepts or blocks the communication.
3. After the OTP chain runs empty, the two communicators exchange a new secret and reinitialize (1.).

This structure is generally effective for multi-client environments and communication with many REST-Communicators. I have several questions regarding this procedure:

1. Is the calculation of OTPs **fast enough** to handle ms-transactions on the clients?
2. Is the overhead of the OTPs **comparatively small** in contrast to other security-features?
3. Is a OTP-procedure **more secure** than TLS-communication?
4. Could OTP-security be a method to use over **HTTP**-channels? (Assuming, it's ok that the data is plain readable!)
5. Which security-implementations are as secure as the explained procedure, but are **cheaper, faster or less error-prone**?

Thanks in advance. Please correct me, if the question has any mistakes or is out-of-scope!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want the OTP generated for every request, which means (as you don't know the time the reqest will be send) you have to calculate the OTPs at least every second. Could be a problem with latency. Comparing OTP and TLS is like comparing apples and oranges. ;-)

Comment: I can imagine generating the OTP on demand or frequently every time unit. With TLS I meant to simply use HTTPS as transport protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've read your question more thoroughly and understood it now. :-)

1. If you are pre-generating a list of OTPs on both sides there should
   be no problem regarding performance. However you need to secure the
   storage of the OTPs, which could be tricky regarding who has access
   to the systems.
2. The overhead is IMHO insignificant when you are pregenerating the
   list.
3. TLS is transportlayer security, OTP applicationlayer so there is no
   direct comparability. TLS < 1.2 may be unsecure, but so are OTPs if
   the way to generate them is weak. Which brings me to the next point:
4. If you send the OTPs unencrypted it may be possible to do a
   man-in-the-middle and reengineer the algorithm and predict the next
   OTPs.
5. Less error prone as in means of already used in production would be
   for example [Jax-RS secured with CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html). Cheaper? Could be, depends
   on the implementation of the OTPs (buy, make, etc.) Faster? No. As
   stated in answers to 1 and 2: If you have pre-generated OTPs there's not much overhead.

Regardless of the answers above: You should always think twice before implementing a custom solution in this area, as mistakes can be crucial. Think about the threats to your communication, do a trade-off-analysis and look at the result. Perhaps you will be satisfied using TLS > 1.2?